# Not received ether in my account

Tags: rinkeby

I have requested Ether from Rinkeby faucet 23 hours ago. It was successfull and I can see success transaction on Etherscan. But, I have not received ether in my ethereum account yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait for the whole nodes are finished syncing, because your transaction is on the higher block than your local node.
I am also facing the same question as yours, and I am waiting for the syncing from block 0 to highest block.

Answer (score 0):

Show us your transaction hash.

Normally I prefer to use Ropsten for better accessibility and ease of getting ETH.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/62732)